# Android Studio Как переформатировать иконку, чтобы она стала доступной для Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, vector, drawable

У меня есть проблема: я сделал SVG изображение-иконку для приложения, загрузил в Android Studio и вижу:[image: Окно добавления векторного Asset в приложения с пустым Preview]

Я стал искать в чём проблема, но так и не выяснил. Есть лишь предположения, что не работает именно градиент. Но не думаю, что Android настолько опустился, что не поддерживает банальные градиенты.

Вот сама иконка (в низком разрешении):
[image: Иконка приложения в низком разрешении]

Вот код:
[image: Код]
defs:
[image: Код внутри defs]